# How can I change this Python code to be multiprocess rather than multi threaded?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

The Python code below connects to lots of servers, grabs some info from each one and returns the results. It currently kicks off a separate thread for each connection. I would like to see how performance is affected by using a separate process for each connection rather than a thread. Can this code be easily changed to use processes instead of threads? What exactly would I need to do? What are the risks, if any?

Python 2.6 / Platform Linux

```
class ServerInfoGetter(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, host, port=DEFAULT_PORT, timeout=15):
        self.host = host
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.port = port
        self.result = None
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def get_result(self):
        return self.result

    def run(self):
        try:
            serv_check = ServCheck(self.host, \
                                    port=self.port, \
                                    timeout=self.timeout)
            serv_check.get_info()
            self.result = serv_check
        except Exception, err:
            logging.debug("Could not run ServCheck for : %s %s",self.host, err)


def process_hosts(hosts_and_ports):

    def producer(queue, hosts_and_ports):
        for host, ports in hosts_and_ports.items():
            for  port in ports:
                logging.info("processing host: %s:%s", host, port)
                thread = ServerInfoGetter(str(host), port)
                thread.start()
                queue.put(thread, True) # True so block until slot available

    results = []

    def consumer(queue, total_checks):
        while len(results) < total_checks:
            thread = queue.get(True)
            thread.join()
            results.append(thread.get_result())

    logging.info("processing hosts")
    queue = Queue(QUEUE_SIZE)
    prod_thread = threading.Thread(target=producer,
                                    args=(queue,
                                    hosts_and_ports))

    cons_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer,
                                    args=(queue,
                                    calculate_total_checks(hosts_and_ports)))
    prod_thread.start()
    cons_thread.start()
    prod_thread.join()
    cons_thread.join()
    return results
```

Comment: @David: Eeek! Talk about overkill!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html):

> `multiprocessing` is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the `threading` module. [...]  In `multiprocessing`, processes are spawned by creating a `Process` object and then calling its `start()` method. Process follows the API of `threading.Thread`.

So, basically, you just have to replace all `threading.Thread` objects with `multiprocessing.Process` objects (and similarly, the queue needs to be replaced with a `multiprocessing.Queue` object).

At least, that's how it would appear.  However, in practice, **all** objects that need to cross `Process` boundaries need to be [`multiprocessing.Value`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) objects.  Otherwise, they will never update across threads.

This includes `self.host`, `self.timeout`, `self.port`, `self.result` if you're only going to modify the `ServerInfoGetter` class.  Read the rest of the multiprocessing doc to get an idea for the other data types that you'll need to use.

Also, as a sidenote, I'm not sure if it would be a problem for python 2.6 on Linux, but for python 2.7 on Windows, both idle and the interactive interpreter have trouble (for me, at least) with multiprocessing.  These problems go away when directly executing the script with the python or pythonw executables. **Update** - python 2.5.1 on my Slackware box doesn't have this problem, so you may be fine in interactive mode as well... although winwaed wasn't, so who knows...?

Comment: I have seen these problems with Ubuntu 10 as well.

Comment: in interactive mode, you mean?  Do you know which version of python?

Comment: python 2.6.6. problems when selecting "run" in the editor menu. runs fine on the command line with "python myprog.py". Haven't tried multiprocessing in true interactive typing-it-in mode. My scripts use map_async for a map-reduce algorithm across multiple CPUs. I'm also using psycopg which might influence things.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a single process and a single thread e.g. by using [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) ?
The multi process option may only be reasonably easy when os.fork is available....

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I'm using Python 2.6 and Linux. I've updated the Q. So I don't think there's a problem kicking off multiple processes.

Comment: I agree, utilizing multiple cores of a processor really falls into the category of "premature optimization" at least until you're at the point of utilizing multiple servers. And at that point, if you scale over multiple servers it's trivial to scale over multiple cores by treating each core as its own server.

Comment: Agreed. Multiprocessing is the wrong solution for this type of problem but async, as in Twisted's Deferreds, is the right solution.